InterpreterException in Apache Zeppelin V 0.11.1 executing a paragraph
Problem Description:
We tried to start Apache Zeppelin 0.11.1 on the following server.
We followed the installation instructions on the official Apache Zepplin website.
Apache Zeppelin can be started and the notebooks open.
When executing a paragraph, the attached error message appears.
We first tried to implement the whole thing with Docker.
We then also tested the binary version.
However, the same error occurs in both variants.
System Description:
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1063-aws x86_46)
Java:   1.8.0_412 (OpenJDK Runtime Environment - build 1.8.0_412-8u412-ga-1~20.04.1-b08)
Scala:  2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java1.8.0_412)
Spark:  3.5.1 (Spark Hadoop3)
Zeppelin: 0.11.1 from (https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/quickstart/install.html)



REPOSITORY
TAG
IMAGE ID
CREATED
SIZE




apache/zeppelin
0.11.1
f6b9613cfb44
2 months ago
8.44GB



docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm 
-v /projects/zeppelin/lib:/opt/zeppelin/.m2/repository 
-v /projects/zeppelin/logs:/logs 
-v /projects/zeppelin/notebook:/notebook 
-v /projects/zeppelin/db:/db  
-v /projects/zeppelin/lib/spark-current/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3:/opt/spark
-e ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR='/logs'
-e ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR='/notebook' 
-e ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.memory=16g -Dspark.cores.max=8 -Dspark.io.compression.codec=snappy" 
-e ZEPPELIN_INTP_MEM="-Xmx16g"  
-e SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark 
--name zeppelin apache/zeppelin

Stacktrace:
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Fail to open SparkInterpreter
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:76)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:861)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:186)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:135)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(FIFOScheduler.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Fail to open SparkInterpreter
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:140)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: Error accessing /projects/zeppelin-v2/zeppelin-0.11.1-bin-all/interpreter/spark/._spark-interpreter-0.11.1.jar
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.$anonfun$list$3(AggregateClassPath.scala:113)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.list(AggregateClassPath.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ClassPath.list(ClassPath.scala:36)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ClassPath.list$(ClassPath.scala:36)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.list(AggregateClassPath.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:298)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:250)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.completeInfo(Symbols.scala:1542)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.init(Mirrors.scala:258)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror$lzycompute(Global.scala:74)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:72)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:44)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:301)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:301)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1511)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1213)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain._initialize(IMain.scala:124)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.initializeSynchronous(IMain.scala:146)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkScala212Interpreter.createSparkILoop(SparkScala212Interpreter.scala:195)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.AbstractSparkScalaInterpreter.open(AbstractSparkScalaInterpreter.java:116)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:124)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error accessing /projects/zeppelin-v2/zeppelin-0.11.1-bin-all/interpreter/spark/._spark-interpreter-0.11.1.jar
    at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.scala$reflect$io$FileZipArchive$$openZipFile(ZipArchive.scala:190)
    at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.root$lzycompute(ZipArchive.scala:238)
    at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.root(ZipArchive.scala:235)
    at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.allDirs$lzycompute(ZipArchive.scala:272)
    at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.allDirs(ZipArchive.scala:272)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.ZipArchiveFileLookup.findDirEntry(ZipArchiveFileLookup.scala:76)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.ZipArchiveFileLookup.list(ZipArchiveFileLookup.scala:63)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.ZipArchiveFileLookup.list$(ZipArchiveFileLookup.scala:62)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.ZipAndJarClassPathFactory$ZipArchiveClassPath.list(ZipAndJarFileLookupFactory.scala:58)
    at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.$anonfun$list$3(AggregateClassPath.scala:105)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:231)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:157)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:171)
    at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.scala$reflect$io$FileZipArchive$$openZipFile(ZipArchive.scala:187)
    ... 45 more


Same problem in 0.11.2

I hope my answer is not too late.
I've encountered the same problem and spent three days debugging all the yarn logs and source code.
I believe there is a bug in version 0.11.1.

The bug can be found in the following location: $SPARK_HOME/interpreter. In this subdirectory (I haven't checked any other directories), macOS metadata files are being created and referenced.
In my opinion, the person who built this version used a Mac and accidentally included these metafiles in the release.
If you go to that directory and look at it, including hidden files, you'll see files with the prefix '._' that are being used by RemoteInterpreterServer.

Simple Solution
Use a different version.

In the link below, I've written an article with more information on this issue. (It's in Korean, so you might need to use a browser translator.)
https://velog.io/@on5949/%ED%99%95%EC%8B%A4%ED%95%98%EC%A7%80-%EC%95%8A%EC%9D%8C-zeppelin-0.11.1-%EB%B2%84%EA%B7%B8-%EB%A6%AC%ED%8F%AC%ED%8A%B8
I will report this bug to the Zeppelin developers soon.

Thanks to @oj-kim, I solve the issue by using this Dockerfile
ARG ZEPPELIN_VERSION=0.11.2

FROM apache/zeppelin:${ZEPPELIN_VERSION}

USER root 

RUN rm \
        /opt/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/._spark-interpreter-0.11.1.jar \
        /opt/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/scala-2.12/._spark-scala-2.12-0.11.1.jar \
    || true


Removing the two files was not enough in my case, but inspired of that I placed my CLI in the /interpeter/spark folder and removed all ._* files from all folders and subfolders:
sudo find . -name "._*" -exec rm -f {} \;

and the problem was gone :-)

**Spark Interpreter Settings
**
Binary_Interpreter_Settings_Spark_01
Binary_Interpreter_Settings_Spark_02
Binary_Interpreter_Settings_Spark-Submit_01
Docker_Interpreter_Settings_Spark_01
Docker_Interpreter_Settings_Spark_02
Docker_Interpreter_Settings_Spark_03
Binary_Interpreter_Settings_Spark-Submit_01
